# Split string by List

Tags: c#, string, split

Split string by List:
I have SplitColl with delimeters:

```
xx 
yy
..
..
```

And string like this:

```
strxx
```

When i try to split string:

```
   var formattedText = "strxx";
   var lst = new List<String>();
   lst.Add("xx");
   lst.Add("yy");
   var arr = formattedText.Split(lst.ToArray(), 10, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

I have "str" result;
But how to skip this result? I want to get empty array in this case (when delim is a part of a word).
I expect, that when `formattedText="str xx"`, result is `str`.

EDIT:
I have a many delimeters of address: such as `street,city,town`,etc.
And i try to get strings like: `city DC`-> DC.
But, when i get a word like:`cityacdc`-> i get `acdc`, but it not a name of a city.

Comment: You could just set the list delimiters like `lst.Add(" xx"); lst.Add("xx ");`

Comment: " I expect, that when `formattedText="str xx"`, result is `str`" In this case actually your delimeter is *space*. What you are looking for is a match criterion

Comment: "city DC-> DC" do you want to get the part behind the keyword or before like in your first example?  
" I expect, that when formattedText="str xx", result is str"

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, basically what I'm doing is first I remove any leading or tailing delimiters (only if they are separated with a space) from the formattedText string. Then using the remaining string I split it for each delimiter if it has spaces on both sides.

```
//usage
var result = FormatText(formattedText, delimiterlst);


//code
static string[] FormatText(string input, List<string> delimiters)
{
    delimiters.ForEach(d => {
        TrimInput(ref input, "start", d.ToCharArray());
        TrimInput(ref input, "end", d.ToCharArray());
    });
    return input.Split(delimiters.Select(d => $" {d} ").ToArray(), 10, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
static void TrimInput(ref string input, string pos, char[] delimiter)
{
    //backup
    string temp = input;

    //trim
    input = (pos == "start") ? input.TrimStart(delimiter) : input.TrimEnd(delimiter);
    string trimmed = (pos == "start") ? input.TrimStart() : input.TrimEnd();

    //update string
    input = (input != trimmed) ? trimmed : temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not using your keywords really as delimiters but as search criterion. In this case you could use RegEx to search for each pattern. Here is an example program to illustrate this procedure:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> delim = new List<string> { "city", "street" };

    string formattedText = "strxx street BakerStreet cityxx city London";

    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    foreach (var del in delim)
    {
        string s = Regex.Match(formattedText, del + @"\s\w+\b").Value;

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        {
            results.Add(s.Split(' ')[1]);
        }
    }            

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", results));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This would handle this case:

> And I try to get strings like: city DC --> DC

to handle the case where you want to find the word in front of your keyword:

> I expect, that when formattedText="str xx", result is str

just switch the places of the matching criterion:

```
string s = Regex.Match(formattedText, @"\b\w+\s"+ del).Value;
```

and take the first element at the split

```
results.Add(s.Split(' ')[0]);
```